# printf not printing

Tags: c, char, printf

I have this bit of code for a shallow version of a 'nim' game in order to get to know c. this part is about printing the board game, expected output:

```
---------------
Box 1: ooo
Box 2: oooo
---------------
```

the number of 'o''s in each box is inputted by the user and sent to the function as a parameter.

the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_BOXES 2
void printBoard(int number_of_balls_1, int number_of_balls_2)
{
   int boxes[NUMBER_OF_BOXES] = {number_of_balls_1, number_of_balls_2};
   printf("---------------\n");
   printBoxes(boxes);
   printf("---------------\n");
}

void printBoxes(int boxes[NUMBER_OF_BOXES])
{
    char ball = 'o';
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BOXES; i++)
    {
        printf("Box %d: ", i+1);
        for(int j = 0; j < boxes[i]; ++j)
        {
            printf("%c", ball);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

it *used to* work (three tiring hours ago), i can't figure out what went wrong! now all it's giving me is:

```
"---------------
Box 0: Box 1: ---------------"
```

help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where's your `main` function?

Comment: The output you get seems to be the output you would expect your code to produce. Can you explain what output you expect and why so we can explain where your misunderstanding is?

Comment: Some reason you're using a 1-based index into `boxes[]` instead of the normal 0-based?

Comment: It is impossible to obtain the output `Box 0` with this code. Please double check and post a code consistent with the output `"--------------- Box 0: Box 1: ---------------"` (or viceversa)

Comment: That will not compile. `NUMBER_OF_BOXES` is nothing. Note: use consistent indentation (and do not use GNU-style - it is just ugly). Also you are invoking _undefined behaviour by the `for` loop `i <= ...`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_BOXES 2

void printBoxes(const int boxes[NUMBER_OF_BOXES])
{
    char ball = 'o';
    for(int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_BOXES; i++)
    {
        printf("Box %d: ", i);
        for(int j = 0; j < boxes[i-1]; ++j)
        {
            printf("%c", ball);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printBoard(const int number_of_balls_1, const int number_of_balls_2)
{
    int boxes[NUMBER_OF_BOXES]= {number_of_balls_1, number_of_balls_2};
    printf("---------------\n");
    printBoxes(boxes);
    printf("---------------\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks! i did miss that index over there. does this give you the expected output? because it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_BOXES 2

void printBoxes(const int boxes[NUMBER_OF_BOXES]) {
    char ball = 'o';
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BOXES; i++) {
        printf("Box %d: ", i+1);
        for(int j = 0; j < boxes[i]; ++j) {
            printf("%c", ball);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printBoard(const int number_of_balls_1, const int number_of_balls_2) {
        int boxes[NUMBER_OF_BOXES]= {number_of_balls_1, number_of_balls_2};
        printf("---------------\n");
        printBoxes(boxes);
        printf("---------------\n");
    }

void main() {
    printBoard(3, 4);
}
```

Compile :

```
gcc -std=c99 box.c -o box
```

Output :

```
---------------
Box 1: ooo
Box 2: oooo
---------------
```